# Google Tag manager analytics.js clientId as custom dimension set as an event

Tags: javascript, macros, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, analytics.js

I have analytics.js deployed through GTM using standard fields (no custom html) just macros in assigning the field values for a standard pageview. I am attempting to set the clientId as a custom Dimension in GTM but it doesn't seem to work.

Steps taken:

Tag 1 - Custom html with Firing rule = {{event}} equals gtm.load

```
<script>
 var clientId = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId'); 
 dataLayer.push({'UAID': clientId});
</script>
```

Tag 2 - Standard GTM fields using Universal Beta, Track type = event, and Custom Dimensions index = 1 and Dimension = {{MYMACRO}}

Firing rule = {{event}} equals UAID

MYMACRO = Macro Type as Data Layer Variable, with UAID as the Macro name.

Any thoughts why this is failing? I didn't want to set as pageview to not double count pages, and not as an event (I can push this as an event) but it makes sense to be a Custom Dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not seem to have an event called UAID. Not every variable in the datalayer automatically becomes an event, you need to use the "reserved" varibale name "event":

```
<script>
 var clientId = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId'); 
 dataLayer.push({
    'UAID': clientId,
    'event': 'UAID'
 });
</script>
```